# Get the exchange and routing key in Spring Cloud Stream channel interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have a SpringBoot application making use of Spring Cloud Stream to publish and receive messages to/from RabbitMQ. I implemented a `ChannelInterceptor` using `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` to log incoming and outgoing events. For incoming events I can get all the details I need (like queue name etc.) from the attributes of the `MessageChannel`. However. for outgoing events (published using `StreamBridge.send(bindingName,data)`) the message channel has no attributes. Is there a way to get the destination exchange and routing key from the `ChannelInterceptor`?

Comment: No; that information is determined long after the interceptor has seen the message. There might be some other way to get it, but I will have to think about it. Open an issue on GitHub (spring-cloud-stream) referencing this question.